# How to assign to members of a function?

Tags: javascript, arguments, member, first-class-functions

Since functions are first class objects, it should be possible to assign to the members of them.

Am I right thinking that `arguments.callee` does this?

Are there any other ways to set these fields?

How is it possible to set `field` in first case?

```
function something1() {
    arguments.callee.field = 12;
} 

alert(something1.field); // will show undefined
something1();
alert(something1.filed); // will show 12

something2 = function() {
    arguments.callee.field = 12;
};

alert(something2.field); // will show undefined
something2();
alert(something2.field); // will show 12
```

**UPDATE 1**

I mean how to access members from within function when it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `arguments.callee` to refer to a function that has a name; you can just use the name. This is naturally the case when you declare the function using the

```
function name(...) { ... }
```

syntax; but even in a function expression, you're allowed to supply a temporary name:

```
(function temp_name(...) { ... })(arg);
```

So, if you want to set the properties from inside the function, you can write:

```
function something1() {
    something1.field = 12;
} 

alert(something1.field); // will show undefined
something1();
alert(something1.field); // will show 12

something2 = function something2() { // note the second "something2"
    something2.field = 12;
};

alert(something2.field); // will show undefined
something2();
alert(something2.field); // will show 12
```

Comment: Can I write `something2 = function something3() {...};` and what will be the difference between two names?

Comment: @Dims: Yes, you can. The difference is that the name `something3` is local to the function, whereas the name `something2` will have whatever outer scope you'd expect. So, for example, you might write `var f = function g() { alert(g); }; alert(f); f();` -- with `g` being used inside the function, and `f` being used afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
function something1() {
    this.field = 12;
} 

var test = new something1();

alert(test.field); // alerts "12"
test.field = 42;
alert(test.field); // alerts "42"
```

If you're going to treat it like a class, you need to create a new instance of it before you can access its fields.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDTeN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right thinking that arguments.callee does this?

Yes it did, but now they [deprecated](http://es5.github.com/#C) it.

> Are there any other ways to set these fields?

The official way to replace `callee` is to use an explicit function name, as in `funcName.propertyName=...`. This is however not always convenient, for example, with dynamically generated functions. To quote John Resig, [we're going to miss arguments.callee](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/#postcomment), it was quite useful for specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
function something1() {};
something1.Property = "Foo";
```

You can directly assign the properties to any function just like a normal object. If to say in OOP language create static properties and methods.

**Edit**

The same inside the function

```
function something1() {
     something1.AnotherProp = "Bar";
};
something1.Property = "Foo";
```

Comment: I meant from inside of the function.